# javascript Client side validation in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, dom-events, client-side-validation

I am using Django. I have a template with two input fields and one button. the html code as follows: the page will show results of search in same page itself.

**search.html**

```
<form method="get">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
            <input type="text" id="areasearch" name="asearch" ><hr>
             <button type="submit" id="search" onclick="enteranyone()">Search</button>
 </form>
<p id="note"></p>
<script>
function enteranyone() {
  var sub = document.getElementById("subsearch");
  var area = document.getElementById("areasearch")
  if (sub.value=="") {
    document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = "subject or area required";
    return false
  }
} </script>
```

I want to do client side validation, that any one of the input must be filled. I tired the above code, its working, but not staying for few sec also. How to do overcome this? Should I have to do anything in views.py file? Following is code in views.py:

```
def search(request):
    a=request.GET.get("search",None)
    b=request.GET.get("asearch",None)

    if a or b:
        trail=Trial.objects.filter(name__icontains=a,data__icontains=b)


    context={'trail':trail}
    return render(request,'search.html',context)
```

I want to display "subject or area required" when both input fields are empty. it showing for few sec then disappearing.

Comment: Add an event listener to your form submit. This event listener should check to see if the values of the inputs are empty, if so prevent the form from submitting (preventDefault()) and perform whatever action you need. Otherwise let the form submit.

Is there any reason you aren't using django-filter or django-forms for this?

Comment: @plum0 i already used onclick event handler in submit button. and i preformed operation also. please check the code once showing above.